# Integral $\oint_{\gamma}\frac {\cos z}{z}dz$ on 2 curves

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, complex-integration

$\oint_{\gamma}\frac {\cos z}{z}dz$ on the curve $\gamma = \gamma_1\colon|z| =1$ and $\gamma = \gamma_2\colon|z|=3$. I calculated on $|z| = 1$ but I don't see why it would be different if I would calculate on $|z| = 3$, since I apply the residue formula at $z_0 = 0$. This is what I did:

$$\oint_{\gamma}\frac {\cos z}{z}dz = 2\pi i \operatorname{Res}(f,0)$$
from the Residue Theorem.

We have $\operatorname{Res}(f,0) = \lim_{z\to0}z\frac {\cos(z)}{z} = 1.$ Thus the integral is $I = 2\pi i$ and because the only singular point which is a simple point is contained in both curves then the answer must be the same right?

Comment: As you're already using the powerful Residue Theorem then it is clear you're right. It'd be a little more challenging if you weren't allowed to use that theorem and would, instead, use power series, for example and then go by the definition of complex integral, with a line integral and etc.

Comment: Oh, I see, thank you anyway

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use [Cauchy's integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula#Theorem)
$$f^{(n)}(a)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int\limits_{\gamma}\frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^{n+1}}dz \tag{1}$$
In this case, since $0$ is "inside" $|z|=1$ and $|z|=3$
$$f(0)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int\limits_{\color{red}{|z|=1}}\frac{f(z)}{z}dz$$
$$f(0)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int\limits_{\color{red}{|z|=3}}\frac{f(z)}{z}dz$$
where $f(z)=\cos{z}$ and $f(0)=\cos{(0)}=1$, thus
$$2\pi i=\int\limits_{\color{red}{|z|=1}}\frac{f(z)}{z}dz=\int\limits_{\color{red}{|z|=3}}\frac{f(z)}{z}dz$$